# Adding a 'save to' location to Pages on iPad

Tags: objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I know that it is possible to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to give the user a chance to open a document, say a Word document, in an application such as Pages.

Is it possible in any way to do the reverse: that is, allow a user to save the document back to an area where my application can access the newly saved document, or to provide a 'save to' option within Pages? Like how Dropbox integrates with Pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Apps that support Dropbox do so by implementing the Dropbox API and syncing to the Dropbox server when online. The only way another app can give a file to your app directly is through the UIDocumentInteractionController "Open in.." feature. You can sign up for receiving files of the formats you want to support [like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1): those files will be written temporarily in your app bundle's Documents/Inbox and you will have to save them in another directory to be able to write to them.

Comment: I realise the sandboxing prevents extra-app document access; I guess I wondered whether there was any equivalent to the image picker for Pages. Thanks for the links though

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can't save apps to other application's space due to required app sandboxing.